# How to use an iterator as is in the ECMA6 proposal?

Tags: javascript, iterator, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to figure out how it is intended to use the iterators as defined in the current [ECMA6 draft](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/The_Iterator_protocol).

The iterator is proposed as follows:

```
function makeIterator(array){
    var nextIndex = 0;

    return {
       next: function(){
           return nextIndex < array.length ?
               {value: array[nextIndex++], done: false} :
               {done: true};
       }
    }
}
```

I feel like I'm missing out something, because this would mean you have to use it in this fashion:

```
var it = makeIterator(someArray);
var current = it.next();

while (current.done !== true){
    console.log(current.value);
    current = it.next();
}
```

Because, of course, something like this does skip values:

```
var it = makeIterator(someArray);

while (it.next().done !== true){
    console.log(it.next().value);
}
```

Coming from a Java world I'm confused to why they did not include a `hasNext` function. Because this would allow the following usage:

```
function makeBetterIterator(array){
    var nextIndex = 0;

    return {
       next: function(){
           return nextIndex < array.length ?
               {value: array[nextIndex++], done: false} :
               {done: true};
       },
       hasNext: function(){
            if(nextIndex < array.length){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
       }
    }
}

var someArray = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];

var it = makeBetterIterator(someArray)

while (it.hasNext() === true){
    console.log(it.next().value);
}
```

Is there simpler way to use iterators or is that how it's supposed to be done? If there is no simpler way, why are iterators proposed like this when there's clearly a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid the duplication before the `while` loop, you could do something as simple as this:

```
var it = makeIterator(someArray);

while (true) {
    var current = it.next();
    if (current.done) break;
    console.log(current.value);
}
```

But really, in ES6, you'd be doing this:

```
for (var val of makeIterator(someArray)) {
    console.log(val);
}
```

The ES6 iterator protocol is simple in that the [*Iterator* iterface](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-iterator-interface) only requires a single method (`next`) which returns an [*IteratorResult*](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-iteratorresult-interface) containing `done` and optionally `value`. Once the protocol becomes standard, then anything implementing it will get all of the benefits of language-level statements that support it (like `for...of`).

Answer (score 0):

This does the same as your better iterator, but a bit simpler:

```js
    function makeIterator(array){
        var nextIndex = 0;
    
        return {
           next: function(){
               return nextIndex < array.length ?
                   {value: array[nextIndex++], done: false} :
                   false;
           }
        }
    }
    
    var someArray = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];
    
    var it = makeIterator(someArray);
    
    while (current = it.next()){
        $('body').append(current.value+'<br>');
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [1,2,3];

var it = arr[Symbol.iterator]();


for (var v, res; (res = it.next()) && !res.done; ) {
    v = res.value;
    console.log( v );
}
```

GOOD MANUAL http://2ality.com/2015/02/es6-iteration.html